# USBGuard issue with Realtek NIC on Dell Tablet and Docking Station

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, network-interface, usbguard

I am facing an issue with a Dell Tablet running RHEL 8.9 and utilizing a non-Dell docking station. The docking station is equipped with a Realtek NIC, and I've configured `usbguard` to manage USB device access. The Realtek NIC has been added to the `usbguard` rules, and it is correctly identified after a reboot when the tablet is docked.

However, I've observed a peculiar behavior. After undocking the tablet or if the docking station loses power, the NIC goes down as **expected**. But, when re-docked or when power is restored to the docking station, the *NIC fails to come back to life*.

I've verified that the `usbguard` service is allowing the NIC through, as observed through `usbguard watch`, but the interface does not show up when I run `ip link show`. Even restarting `NetworkManager` doesn't seem to bring the NIC back.

Interestingly, when I completely disable the `usbguard` service, and after a reboot, the NIC successfully comes back to life. Undocking and redocking leads to NIC going down and coming back up without any issues. I have also added the following to capture the journal logs for `NetworkManager` in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/95-logging.conf`

```
[logging]
level=TRACE
domains=ALL
```

`journalctl -xf -u NetworkManager` does not capture **ANY** logs for the interface in question when the tablet is docked back. This is of course with `usbguard` service running.

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this behavior and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.